# Sum of combinations series

Tags: summation, power-series, combinations

What is the value or tight upper limit of the following summation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} x^{k(n-k)}$$

Comment: What did you try so far? If you have already explored some ideas, this will allow the answerers not to waste their time. Also, what's your motivation to study such a polynomial?

Comment: For $n=2$ this is $2x+2$

Comment: The sum represents an expectation of certain phenomenon. x < 1 and the sum from k = 1 to n-1 should coverage with low values of x (x << 1)

Comment: Are you looking for something loose like $2 \le f(n) \le 2^n$ for $x \in (0, 1)$?

Comment: I am looking for an upper bound in terms of n and x which should be more tight.

Answer (score 1):

It is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $(n/2)^2$ if $n$ is even, $(n^2-1)/4$ if $n$ is odd.   The largest coefficients are those for $k$ near $n/2$, and 
those are also the terms with highest degree.  If you are interested in estimates
that are tight for large $x$, that's the place to look...

Comment: I think you could write that as $n^2/4$ to make the connection with the version for odd $n$ immediately apparent.

Comment: What about x<1 this will make the first term 1, (n-1)x^(n-1),... of lower degree and lower coefficient but the series may be increasing or decreasing.

Comment: For small $x$, the terms of low degree will be the important ones, and these are the ones where $k$ is near $0$ or $n$.